# How do i fix the error "The type ApplicationListener is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with the arguments <ContextRefresedEvents>"?

Tags: java, spring

I have the class definition as follows:

```
public class StartEventListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
The type ApplicationListener is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with the arguments <ContextRefresedEvents>
```

I have tried all the other ways that I've seen o fixing this problem and have had no success does anyone know a fix for this issue?

Comment: Not being a java expert, but shouldn't it read "imple_me_nts"?

Comment: By using the correct `ApplicationListener` the one from spring, and to use a version of Spring that has a generic `ApplicationListener` (which means a version of Spring larger then 3.0) it you have an older version you will get this error. If you are using maven use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out which versions are being used (and fix that).

Comment: how do I make sure that eclipse is using the correct application listener?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
```

You're probably using a non-generic `ApplicationListener`

Comment: I have that line in the code and its still shooting me the same error

Comment: Are you using Spring 3 or higher where `ApplicationListener` is generic?

Comment: Yes I'm running spring 4.1.9.

Comment: It seems you have a non-generic `ApplicationListener` class on your classpath. If you can find it - rename or remove it & do a clean rebuild

Comment: where should i look for in in eclipse to be able to edit it

Comment: Use Ctrl + Shift + T and enter `ApplicationListener`

Comment: so i have 4 ApplicationListener's there do i remove them all or...?

Comment: Only remove the ones that conflict with the full class name, i.e. `org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener`..

Comment: it's not letting me remove them

Comment: I found it there was a old spring jar in my directory thanks for the help.